# Sinon: Test function return value

Tags: unit-testing, sinon, spy, enzyme

I am using `Sinon` `Enzyme` for testing. I have a function that takes an array of objects and transform it into a new different array.

```
getContainersByHostId(data) {
    return _.chain(data)
      .groupBy('hostId')
      .toPairs()
      .map(currentItem => _.zipObject(['hostId', 'containers'], currentItem))
      .value();
  }
```

**Args:**

```
const containers = [{
          id: 'c_01',
          hostId: 'h_01',
          hostIp: '192.168.1.0',
          name: 'Some Container'
        }];
```

**Result:**

```
[{hostId: 'h_01',
containers: [{
hostId: 'h_01',
ip: '192.168.1.0',
id: 'c_01',
name: 'Some Container'
}]}];
```

This works fine. However, the issue I am facing is in the unit test. So currently I have this.

```
const containers = [{
          id: 'c_01',
          hostId: 'h_01',
          hostIp: '192.168.1.0',
          name: 'Indigo Container'
        }];

        const wrapper = shallow(<Groups {...props} />);
        const instance = wrapper.instance();
        sandbox.stub(instance, 'getContainersByHostId');
        instance.getContainersByHostId(containers);
        expect(instance.getContainersByHostId.calledWith(containers)).to.equal(true);
      });
```

How to test if the args that are passed equal to new array?

**Update:**

I have tried `returnValue` but it gives me false and I couldn't find any possible solution to check what it's really returning.

Comment: What exactly do you want to assert? I guess you should have 2 arrays, one for the input, and second for the expected output. So you just assert that calling `getContainersByHostId` with that input should return expected output. Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: That's exactly what I want to assert. But when I assert it against the output array it gives me undefined. Can you maybe write an example how I can achieve that. Maybe I am doing something wrong. I'll edit my question as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, when you are stubbing a function, you cancel all it's behaviour, so if you do not specify some value for this stub to return then it will return `undefined`. Most probably you've confused it with `sinon.spy()`.

If I understood you correctly all you need can be achieved even more easier. No need in *Sinon* at all. Something like:

```
const modified = instance.getContainersByHostId(inputArray);    
expect(modified).to.eql(expectedArray);
```

Comment: Okay I knew I was doing something really stupid here. You are right. But I am not sure I get your first point. The point where you said I would have to specify return value? Can you please elaborate that? I basically want to understand why it was throwing `undefined` in the first place.

Comment: And with what you said, are you saying that I don't have to spy or make stub of class methods? Since, you directly asserted on the original function? I was under the impression, we ought to do this with spies or stubs? I will be really thankful if you could explain this to me in depth.

Comment: Ok, since there is a manual function call in your test case: `instance.getContainersByHostId(containers);` you don't need to spy or stub anything. Stubbing or spying is used when you do not control the function call. In most cases they are used in the situation when you call something, that triggers spied method. 

As for _specify return value_, I was mentioning `stub.returns(obj);` This method makes the stub return the provided value. You can take a closer look to the Sinon api here: http://sinonjs.org/docs/

Comment: Man, this is really helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to help you! :)